# Oracle Database 12c installation issue

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I'm getting "ADR setup(diagsetup) tool failed. " issue after installing 78% and the log file is showing this:

```
ID: oracle.install.ivw.common.driver.DiagsetupToolJob:10534
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program    "C:\app\Ephrem\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\diagsetup.bat": CreateProcess   error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.processException(ProcessBuilder.java:478)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:457)
at   oracle.install.commons.system.process.ProcessLauncher.start(ProcessLauncher.java:60)
at   oracle.install.commons.system.process.ProcessLauncher.launchProcess(ProcessLaunc   her.java:88)
at    oracle.install.commons.system.process.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.java:147)
at   oracle.install.ivw.common.driver.DiagsetupToolJob.call(DiagsetupToolJob.java:165)
at oracle.install.ivw.common.driver.DiagsetupToolJob.call(DiagsetupToolJob.java:207)
at oracle.install.ivw.common.driver.DiagsetupToolJob.call(DiagsetupToolJob.java:56)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:273)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:31)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
... 11 more
```

Any Idea to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the following blog. The same should work for you. Hope this will help. The problem is because of the antivirus program. Try uninstalling it first and then install the database.

http://softechstuff.blogspot.in/2015/08/oracle-database-12cinstallation.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Eventually solved by increasing RAM memory.

This issues occurs when not enough memory is available to oracle resources, so increase your system space before installed it (RAM also).

Note: Before installation check that previous install version completely uninstalled even no environment variables present.